# Problema com tr da table inserida via javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

```js
 function cadProd(){
 var nomeProd = document.getElementById("nomeProd").value;
 var categoria = document.getElementById("categoria").value;
 var descricao = document.getElementById("descricao").value;
 var un = document.getElementById("un").value;
 var qtd = document.getElementById("qtd").value;
 var qtdMin = document.getElementById("qtdMin").value;
 var table = document.getElementById("novosProds");
 var row = table.insertRow(1);
 row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = nomeProd;
 row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = categoria;
 row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = descricao;
 row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = un;
 row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = qtd;
 row.insertCell(5).innerHTML = qtdMin;
 row.insertCell(6).innerHTML = '<input type="submit" value="Deletar">';
 return alert("Registro realizado com sucesso");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE pt-br>
<html>
 <head>

 </head>
 <body>
  <?php/*
   include 'header.php';
  */?>
  <div class='cadProd'>
   <h1>Cadastrar Produto</h1>
   <table border='2' id='cadastrar'>
    <tr>
     <th>Nome</th><th>Categoria</th><th>Descrição</th><th>Un. Medida</th><th>Qtd</th><th>Qtd Minima</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><form method='POST'>
     <td>
      <input type='text' name='nomeProd' id='nomeProd'/>
     </td>
     <td>
      <select name='categoria' id='categoria'>
       <option id='1'>Limpeza</option>
       <option id='2'>Escritório</option>
       <option id='3'>Uniforme</option>
       <option id='4'>Acessórios</option>
      </select>
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type='descricao' name='descricao' id='descricao'>
     </td>
     <td>
      <select name='un' id='un'>
       <option id='1'>Un</option>
       <option id='2'>Pct</option>
       <option id='3'>Lts</option>
       <option id='3'>Kilo</option>
      </select>
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type='number' name='qtd' id='qtd'>
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type='number' name='qtdMin' id='qtdMin'>
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type='submit' onclick='cadProd()' value='Cadastrar'/>
     </td>
    </form></tr>
   </table>
   <table border='2' id='novosProds'>
    <tr>
     <th>Nome</th><th>Categoria</th><th>Descrição</th><th>Un. Medida</th><th>Qtd</th><th>Qtd Minima</th>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 
 <body>
</html>
```

Galera, se verificarem o exemplo, ele está mantendo a linha. Meu problema é que quando isso é executado aqui no meu localhost, ele deleta a linha após a inserir.

Esse código é ele completo. Se salvar como html pode ver o problema:

```
<!DOCTYPE pt-br>
```

```
</head>
<body>
    <div class='cadProd'>
        <h1>Cadastrar Produto</h1>
        <table border='2' id='cadastrar'>
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th><th>Categoria</th><th>Descrição</th><th>Un. Medida</th><th>Qtd</th><th>Qtd Minima</th>
            </tr>
            <tr><form method='POST'>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' name='nomeProd' id='nomeProd'/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name='categoria' id='categoria'>
                        <option id='1'>Limpeza</option>
                        <option id='2'>Escritório</option>
                        <option id='3'>Uniforme</option>
                        <option id='4'>Acessórios</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type='descricao' name='descricao' id='descricao'>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name='un' id='un'>
                        <option id='1'>Un</option>
                        <option id='2'>Pct</option>
                        <option id='3'>Lts</option>
                        <option id='3'>Kilo</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type='number' name='qtd' id='qtd'>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type='number' name='qtdMin' id='qtdMin'>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type='submit' onclick='cadProd()' value='Cadastrar'/>
                </td>
            </form></tr>
        </table>
        <table border='2' id='novosProds'>
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th><th>Categoria</th><th>Descrição</th><th>Un. Medida</th><th>Qtd</th><th>Qtd Minima</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
        <script language='javascript'>
function cadProd(){
var nomeProd = document.getElementById("nomeProd").value;
var categoria = document.getElementById("categoria").value;
var descricao = document.getElementById("descricao").value;
var un = document.getElementById("un").value;
var qtd = document.getElementById("qtd").value;
var qtdMin = document.getElementById("qtdMin").value;
var table = document.getElementById("novosProds");
var row = table.insertRow(1);
row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = nomeProd;
row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = categoria;
row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = descricao;
row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = un;
row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = qtd;
row.insertCell(5).innerHTML = qtdMin;
row.insertCell(6).innerHTML = '<input type="submit" value="Deletar">';
return alert("Registro realizado com sucesso");
```

}

Alguma sugestão sobre isso? Atenciosamente

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="Deletar">` um input do tipo submit "submete o formulario para uma acao, nao vi nenhuma acao no click e nemhum formulario no html. O que deve estar acontecendo no seu deletar em localhost nao é ele estar dando um refresh na pagina? E com isso o registro some e voce acha que apagou?

Comment: Na verdade não está relacionado a este input DELETAR, mas sim ao que está no formulário acima, que contém o value='cadastrar'. Mas o que disse está correto. O script estava dando um refresh na página e os registros sumiam após serem inseridos. Muito obrigado pela ajuda Neuber.

Comment: O código parece está correto, pode ser algum cache ou diferença no seu código local não? O javascript roda no navegador, então não faz diferença se você está rodando em um site real ou em local host, se estiver em http(s):// , agora executando como arquivo html sem estar por servidor web pode estar causando algum problema.
Talvez seja a hora de aprender angularjs :) http://plnkr.co/edit/d6yDka?p=preview

Comment: Troque o <input type="submit" value"Deletar"> por <button type="button">Deletar</button>

O input type submit submete para o atributo action do <form>, caso ele não exista ele vai requisitar a própria página com o método POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando se utiliza [type="submit"] o navegador irá fazer um POST request à URL ou URI atributo "action" definida  na tag , caso não exista a action ou o form, o click em um [type="submit"] irá executar um POST na própria página, o que resultará num redirect, como seu código não possui nenhum mecanismo de persistência os dados são perdidos devido ao refresh da página.
Alterando o   `<input type="submit" value"(...)">`  por   `<button type="button">(...)</button>`

Abaixo segue o código modificado para essa realidade:

```js
 function cadProd(){
  var nomeProd = document.getElementById("nomeProd").value;
  var categoria = document.getElementById("categoria").value;
  var descricao = document.getElementById("descricao").value;
  var un = document.getElementById("un").value;
  var qtd = document.getElementById("qtd").value;
  var qtdMin = document.getElementById("qtdMin").value;
  var table = document.getElementById("novosProds");
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = nomeProd;
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = categoria;
  row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = descricao;
  row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = un;
  row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = qtd;
  row.insertCell(5).innerHTML = qtdMin;
  row.insertCell(6).innerHTML = '<button type="button"  onclick="delProd(this)">Deletar</button>';
  return alert("Registro realizado com sucesso");
 }
 function delProd(td) {
  var tr=td.parentNode.parentNode;
  tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
 }
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE pt-br>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
 <?php/*
  include 'header.php';
 */?>
 <div class='cadProd'>
  <h1>Cadastrar Produto</h1>
  <table border='2' id='cadastrar'>
   <tr>
    <th>Nome</th><th>Categoria</th><th>Descrição</th><th>Un. Medida</th><th>Qtd</th><th>Qtd Minima</th>
   </tr>
   <tr><form method='POST'>
    <td>
     <input type='text' name='nomeProd' id='nomeProd'/>
    </td>
    <td>
     <select name='categoria' id='categoria'>
      <option id='1'>Limpeza</option>
      <option id='2'>Escritório</option>
      <option id='3'>Uniforme</option>
      <option id='4'>Acessórios</option>
     </select>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type='descricao' name='descricao' id='descricao'>
    </td>
    <td>
     <select name='un' id='un'>
      <option id='1'>Un</option>
      <option id='2'>Pct</option>
      <option id='3'>Lts</option>
      <option id='3'>Kilo</option>
     </select>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type='number' name='qtd' id='qtd'>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type='number' name='qtdMin' id='qtdMin'>
    </td>
    <td>
     <button type="button" onclick="cadProd()">Cadastrar</button>
    </td>
   </form></tr>
  </table>
  <table border='2' id='novosProds'>
   <tr>
    <th>Nome</th><th>Categoria</th><th>Descrição</th><th>Un. Medida</th><th>Qtd</th><th>Qtd Minima</th>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
<body>
</html>
```

Basicamente eu removi os inputs type submit e substitui por buttons do tipo button que não disparam o evento submit. 
Precisei adicionar uma função exclusiva pra remoção do produto, nela eu passo o próprio elemento clicado e então vou subindo até chegar na tabela aonde eu faço a remoção do elemento.